# Neo4j cypher: Deleting a collection of relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I think this may be a bug, however, when deleting a collection of relationships the start node is also deleted. I am running neo4j community edition 2.3.3 and have run the following queries in order.

`match (u:User)-[]->(p:Pie)-[c:CONSISTS_OF*1]->() where id(u) = 6398 and id(p)= 6436 return p,c` Which returns `Displaying 3 nodes, 2 relationships.` and the graph in the image[image: Displaying 3 nodes, 2 relationships.]

`match (u:User)-[]->(p:Pie)-[c:CONSISTS_OF*1]->() where id(u) = 6398 and id(p)= 6436 FOREACH( q in c | DELETE q)` Which results in `Deleted 2 relationships, statement executed in 103 ms.`

And then what I am finding is instead of the collection of relationships c being deleted, the node p is also deleted…

`match (u:User)-[]->(p:Pie)-[c:CONSISTS_OF*1]->() where id(u) = 6398 and id(p)= 6436 return p` Which results in `(no rows)`

I would simply like to delete the collection of relationships. I also feel like this feature is something that makes sense but hasn’t been revisited since late 2013… https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/1612

EDIT: In an earlier version of the question I had DETACH DELETE instead of DELETE. This was a mistake in the posting of the question. I have since revised it. It should be noted that the reason I think this may be a bug is because both DETACH DELETE and DELETE behave the same in this scenario.

Comment: How do you know that `(p:Pie)` has been deleted? In the `MATCH` query that you use to check you still include the `-[c:CONSISTS_OF*1]->` part of the pattern. That part doesn't match anything, because you deleted those relationships. But then the whole pattern won't match anything either. What does `MATCH (p:Pie) WHERE id(p) = 6436` give you?

Comment: Wow, yeah totally overlooked that. You are absolutely correct. If you would like to publish yours as the answer I will close this question. I am somewhat embarrassed I overlooked that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `MATCH` query that you use to check whether the `(p:Pie)` node exists after deleting the relationships you still include the `-[c:CONSISTS_OF*1]->` part of the pattern. That part doesn't match anything, because you deleted those relationships. But then the whole pattern won't match anything either, whether or not the node still exists.

You can use `MATCH (p:Pie) WHERE id(p) = 6436` to test that the `(p:Pie)` node still exists.